# image stream using camera

Tags: opencv, ros-indigo, cv-bridge, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,

My question might seem easy for many since i am still fresh in Ros and Opencv.
I am following the tutorials provided on Ros Website. I am going through the tutorial ''Converting between ROS images and OpenCV images (C++)''.
I am trying to solve point no. 4 in this tutorial ''An example ROS node''. I ran my system and did the catkin_make and it works fine. However, for running the node i need to provide an image stream from a camera. How can I do that. I don't know where to go from there.

I would definitely appreciate any help.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286087/image-stream-using-camera/) by [Firoooo](https://answers.ros.org/users/34248/firoooo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have a webcam or a laptop camera, you should be able to publish the image stream using the `video_stream_opencv` package: http://wiki.ros.org/video_stream_opencv

I've used that package successfully to publish a video stream either from a video device (/dev/video0, for example) or from a video file (something.avi, for example).

---

Originally posted by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) with karma: 1563 on 2018-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0